# Question related to Magma

Tags: abstract-algebra, magma

I am reading some notes in which I found the following exercise:

> Suppose $G$ is a magma then $G$ is associative and satisfy cancellation properties.

I think this is not true for instance matrix multiplication does not satisfy the cancellation property so I think some assumption is missing from the exercise. What could be possible minimum assumption to make the question meaningful.

Comment: There is not much hope for us to guess what the author meant here.

Comment: Hi! Can you reference the notes you are reading or add a larger part of text? @TobiasKildetoft is right, this way one can only make a guess and this would not be much beneficial...

Answer (score 2):

Classically, a magma is just a set with a binary operation. This operation has no reason, without more hypothesis, to be associative or to satisfy cancellation properties.